# Как использовать ajax в shortcode wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Есть допустим такой shortcode

```
function update_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
...
return $newContent;
}
```

Использую потом зацепку

```
add_shortcode('myUpdateShortCode','update_shortcode');
```

Собственно есть файл ajax.php в котором:

```
define( 'DOING_AJAX', true );
define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../wp-load.php' );
add_action("wp_ajax_my_update_for_shortcode", "update_shortcode");

function my_update_for_shortcode()
{
update_shortcode($_GET['atts'], $_GET['content']);
die();
}
```

Все ли правильно?

Answer (score -1):

Не понятно что Вы пытаетесь выполнить. Чтото наплутано:

```
add_shortcode('myUpdateShortCode','update_shortcode');
```

myUpdateShortCode - Это код шорткода, который будет вызываться в форнтенде через [myUpdateShortCode] или do_shortcode('[myUpdateShortCode]');
update_shortcode - Функция update_shortcode() которая будет вызыватся при вставке шорткода.

Файл ajax.php доцельно ли создавать ? Можно те же действия поместить в functions.php
Ещо, скорее всего нужно додать в файл ajax :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_update_for_shortcode', 'my_update_for_shortcode' );
```

Также коментарий к строке :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_update_for_shortcode', 'update_shortcode');
```

Будет вызывать функцию update_shortcode(), не my_update_for_shortcode(), следует заменить на :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_update_for_shortcode', 'my_update_for_shortcode');
```